# android - smooth animation of changing height of a view

Tags: android, animation

I wanted to animate changing *height* of a **TextView** from 0 to its real height. I'm using this code:

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, height)
                        .setDuration(1000);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        textView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        textView.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
```

But the animation is not that smooth (not awful, but I think it can be smoother).

What are the ways to make the smoothest animations of this sort?

Comment: U'd better off write in comments about the reason of downvoting than just downvote.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for its not smooth is because you are setting layout height in each update call and requesting layout too which can be cpu intensive when done several times in a second. The more smoother way i can suggest is Keeping the textview visibility as gone and then setting it to visible in code.

Then you can animate the transition using animation set. Also if you dont want to customise the animation and only want it to animate into position you can use default animation by specifying below xml attribute to the parent layout of your textview

```
    android:animateLayoutChanges= "true"
```

Then when you set Visibility as visible in your code like below

```
    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Your textview will automatically animate into its place.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes. I hope it will help you.

```
textView.setScaleY(0);
textView.setScaleX(0);

textView.animate()
                .scaleY(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .setDuration(200)
                .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                .start();
```

Declare INTERPOLATOR as a class level variable like below code.

```
private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
```

This will give you a very smooth animation. And you can play with this piece of code and can animate as you need.You can change the INTERPOLATOR.
Learn more about [INTERPOLATOR](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html).

Comment: it's smooth, but not what I need :) I need it to stay on the same place and just change the height from 0 to the actual height so that every time unit you see the more text of the TextView. Maybe I just don't need "translationY", but something else

Comment: Ok got it.Try the below lines of code.                                        `textView.setScaleY(0);
            textView.setScaleX(0);

            textView.animate()
                    .scaleY(1)
                    .scaleX(1)
                    .setDuration(400)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                    .start();`

Comment: the problem with "scale" is that the text itself is scaled too, not only TextView. What I need - is like it's a white layout (not transparent) above the TextView and it's like this layout smoothly goes down outside the screen (TextView is at the very bottom). It should look like this. Maybe adding this layout is the only way, idk :)

Comment: Can you explain little bit more about what exactly you want?Then I will try to help you.

Comment: just imagine that TextView initially is not seen and then you see just a part of it (e.g., 25% of height and 25% of all text lines respectively) then more (e.g.50% of height) and till the full height. But it's animated and smooth